# Create model objects from custom Form/Formset in Django

Tags: python, django, post, django-forms, formset

I'm trying to create a simple Django app where I want to have a set of `Question` objects. Each question has it's own list of available answers. I want to display a number of these questions on a view and create objects based on the user data.

It's the last part (create objects based on user-data) that I'm unable to achieve. Here's what I have:

```
class BaseQuestionFormset(BaseFormSet):
    def __init__(self, question_list, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BaseQuestionFormset, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.question_list = question_list

    def get_form_kwargs(self, index):
        kwargs = super(BaseQuestionFormset, self).get_form_kwargs(index)
        if self.question_list and index < len(self.question_list):
            kwargs['question'] = self.question_list[index]
        else:
            kwargs['question'] = None
        return kwargs

class QuestionForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, question, *args, **kwargs):
        super(QuestionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if question:
            choice_list = [x for x in question.get_answers_list()]
            self.fields["answers"] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=choice_list,
                                                widget=RadioSelect)

            self.fields['answers'].label = question.content
```

I'm creating the form as follows:

```
question_formset = formset_factory(QuestionForm, BaseQuestionFormset, extra=len(questions))
formset = question_formset(question_list=questions)
```

Then, when I get user-input, I'm creating the formset as follows:

```
question_formset = formset_factory(QuestionForm, BaseQuestionFormset, extra=3) // 3 is for debug purposes
formset = question_formset(question_list=None, data=request.POST)
```

I'm left with an empty formset that doesn't have any of the data that the users input. I'd appreciate any pointers on what I'm doing wrong and how I can fix it.

Thanks!

Edit: 
Not using `ModelForm` because I have the ad-hoc `answers` field on my `QuestionForm`. ModelForm put constraints on me that I want to avoid. For eg, I'm working with sub-classes of `Question` such as `BoolQuestion`, etc and I had trouble getting this to work with `ModelForm`.

Comment: I did some further debugging and found that `formset.is_valid()` and `form.is_valid` are both `true`. However, there are no `fields` on the `form` that is generated. Digging into `formsets.py` and `forms.py`, I found that the `answers` field is never passed into the form that is being created.

Comment: Can you show the code in view.py, where ou are catching the response?

Comment: @ger.s.brett I ended up working around this issue by just creating forms manually instead of using a Formset. It was both easier to understand and to manipulate.